# Using Node.js code with an Apache Cordova Application in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, visual-studio, cordova

I am an experienced programmer with the Visual Studio tools for Apache Cordova in developing mobile applications but very new to Node.js and its components.

I know that it is possible to create web applications with Node.js through a given template but my question is how can one create a web based mobile application for devices like iphone and android using functions from Node.js code and is this implementation even possible?

Ideally i am looking to add one function that uses Node.js tools to my Apache Cordova Application and want to know how i can implement that function into a HTML/CSS/JS based project and if the implementation will work on mobile devices.

I have done some research already and have not been able to find any pages or tutorials on this subject so any advice would help

Comment: Do you mean you want a simple node.js api to interact with from your cordova ios/android app?

Comment: yes thats it @OliverJ90

Comment: Creating a few API end points in node.js is pretty simple. If you want something that's easy to deploy and a walk through guide maybe check out the node.js getting started guides on Heroku. Provisioning a Db with PostgreSQL is pretty easy too. Let me know if that's not what you had in mind.

Comment: I don't think it is.  I asked a question about a week ago on this site and the answer suggested to me included a section of code that used Node.js which I am unfamiliar with as to how i can use it in a cordova application.  Here is the question and the code is in the checked answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377732/how-to-pull-data-counter-from-a-website-to-use-in-another-html-project-as-a-js-v/32379577?noredirect=1#comment52904903_32379577

Comment: Well, I'd say getting familiar with node would be a good start, that is a pretty simple implementation. Calling an api endpoint from inside a cordova app is as simple as an ajax request to that endpoint with any authorization headers/parameters as you may (or may not) need. I just don't know exactly what you want to achieve (unless it is what you just linked). But if its a simple 2 way data transfer with DB in node then the heroku getting started docs will definitely help you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been researching myself, and the best route seems to be the Ionic/AngularJs/Node.js/Cordova one... I'm also trying to use Visual Studio for this.